# Voyager : VoyagerBreadController not found

Tags: laravel, controller, voyager

I want to create custom controller in Voyager admin package, but I got this error message :

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Back\VoyagerBreadController' not found

1. I added the new controller name to the bread.

[image]

2. I created a namespace a folder `/Back` in `App/Http/Controllers`
3. I created a file `BookingController.php`
4. My `BookingController`:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Back;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BookingController extends VoyagerBreadController
{
    .......
}
```

I also tried to edit  this line of `voyager.php` to the new controller namespace but I got the same error.

```php
'controllers' => [
    'namespace' => 'TCG\\Voyager\\Http\\Controllers',
],
```

I have checked and `VoyagerBreadController` does exist!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is pretty clear, if you read carefully... You are extending `VoyagerBreadController` in your `BookingController` class but you are not telling where does `VoyagerBreadController` come from, because you have created a new folder `Back`, I assume you have only created the controller `BookingController` in that folder, so it cannot find `VoyagerBreadController` in the same folder...

Comment: Thanks, for  the reply. I copied VoyagerBreadController into the Back folder and I got same error.

Comment: Does the `VoyagerBreadController` have the correct namespace ? It should be `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Back;`. Can you share the file with us ? Also try running `composer dump-autoload` when you copy the file, but that should work.